# Why derivate about time is same as about the term themself?

Tags: calculus

$$v=\frac{\pi\,r^2h}{3}$$

The situation is about water flow into a cone tank.

The book gives a condition that $h=2\,r$ so you get:

$$v=\frac{\pi\,h^3}{12}$$

When calculate $\frac{dv}{dt}$:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\pi\,h^3}{12}\right)$$
Did I write above expression correct?

The result is:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{\pi}{12} \times 3h^2 = \frac{\pi\,h^2}{4} \frac{dh}{dt}$$

//Missed the dh/dt at the end. Fixed it.

It look like the **$\frac{d}{dt} h^3$ is same as $\frac{d}{dh} h^3$**

Question:

Why the $d/dt$ is same as $d(\text{term})/d(\text{the term themself})$?

Is it because the $d/dt$ , the derivate about time = rate of change.

And it's same as derivate. So that's why they are same?

Or it just a symbol?!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematics

Comment: It should be $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dt}\frac{dv}{dh}$.

Comment: Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: You have the volume as a function of $h$, which is a function of $t$. So $v(h(t))$, to differentiate it over $t$, you have to apply the chain rule, so it is missing the $\frac{dh}{dt}$ (look at @J.G. comment)

Comment: 1. I'm not sure why volume is a function of t. Is it because the volume change with time? 2. Not sure why you write h(t), Is it same as above, the volume changes so the height changes. Then "h" is function of t?

Comment: Ahh my head is not clear. It's deep night. The @J.G. mentioned is for v(h(t)) , I don't know what is dh/dt now!!!!! Is dh/dt same as dh/dh? is the expression $\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{pih^3}{12})$ correct?

Comment: I don't know what is dh/dt now!!!!! Is dh/dt same as dh/dh? Maybe I'm not understand the meaning of the symbol well? The dh/dt is things about h(t) , the dh/dh is derivate of the term h only. The term contain h can be anywhere, But h(t) is only inside function v? Is it right? @Daniel Cunha

Comment: Well, $dh/dh=1$.

Comment: It might be clearer if you go through step by step from the beginning, now that you have corrected the missing $dh/dt$. Indeed $\frac d{dt}h^3 = \frac d{dh} h^3 \frac{dh}{dt}$, so of course when you forget the $dh/dt$ then it looks like the same thing on both sides. But actually it is just an error.

Comment: If $h$ is not a function of $t$, then $\frac{dh}{dt} = 0$, and therefore, $\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$...